# IdentityServer4 JWT scope as space delimited string instead of array?

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, jwt, openid, identityserver4

I've been trying to understand the IETF RFC for OAuth2 Authorization scopes.
[Scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3)
[OAuth2](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6750.txt)

*The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-delimited, case-sensitive strings.  The strings are defined by the authorization server.  If the value contains multiple space-delimited strings, their order does not matter, and each string adds an additional access range to the requested scope.*

IdentityServer outputs the scope in JWT as an array of strings whereas almost all other providers output the scope as a single space delimited string. Is there an adapter or a configuration setting I can use to have ID4 output the scope in the JWT as a single space delimited string ?

```
"scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "api"
  ],
```

```
"scope": "openid profile email api"
```

Comment: the specs you referred define scope parameter in authorization **request** or `WWW-Authenticate` response **header field**, not a `jwt`. you should not expect space delimited pseudo arrays in json

Answer (score 5):

According to the [RFC8693 draft](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693#section-4.2) and [RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2) (OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection):

> The value of the "scope" claim is a JSON string containing a space-
> separated list of scopes associated with the token, in the format
> described in Section 3.3 of [RFC6749].

And, even though there is not a formal definition written there, [in this other draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-access-token-jwt-07#section-3), the example showed has also the scope items space-separated.

Personally, I would prefer it to be an array (as it would represent better the nature of scope claim), but the space-separated format is indeed more compliant with OAuth2's standard.